# deleting in elastic-search not working

Tags: elasticsearch

i need to remove some documents from my index which meets some criteria.
here is the query:

```
 {"query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
            "match_all":{}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "gte": "2016-01-01",
                        "lte": "2016-10-31"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
     }
  }
```

It fetches me documents between specified date range. `How do i delete these documents`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) API if 5.x or install [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin if 2.x.